# Add parameters vimeo videos using wordpress embeds

Tags: oembed, vimeo

I am using a custom field to embed any supported video on Wordpress
so for example the user enters a video address on the custom field box :

```
http://vimeo.com/72104173
```

and I implemented the following code on my theme :

```
<?php
$videourl = my_meta('video'); // get custom field value
if($videourl!=''){ // if custom field exist  ?>
<?php 
$htmlcode = wp_oembed_get("{$videourl}"); //use oembed  
echo "<div class='video'>{$htmlcode}</div>"; //output the video ?>
...
```

the result/output is below :

```
<iframe ... src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/72104173"></iframe>
```

the problem is that I want to add extra parameters to the vimeo so I can hide the Title and Byline of the video by adding the following to the src :

```
?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0
```

so the final result will be :

```
<iframe ... src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/72104173?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0"></iframe>
```

I tried to user `str_replace` but the problem is that the parameters are added to the end of each video src and the surce is going to be different each time,

really appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: In case anyone else got directed here, this worked for me: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160675/oembed-vimeo-with-add-query-arg-parameters-not-inserted-to-html

Answer (score 4):

There are several filters in WordPress for altering oEmbed data, depending on when you need to modify the results:

1. [embed_handler_html](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_handler_html/)
   *Filters the returned embed handler.*
2. [embed_oembed_html](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_oembed_html/)
   *Filters the cached oEmbed HTML.*
3. [oembed_result](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/oembed_result/)
   *Filters the HTML returned by the oEmbed provider.*

Choose the one that best suits your needs, but keep in mind that each filter acts on data at a different stage of the oEmbed process and could have performance implications.

> For instance, `embed_handler_html`  is called before data is put in the oEmbed / wp_postmeta cache (so only once per external embed) while `embed_oembed_html` is called after retrieving the oEmbed cache (so every time the item is displayed).
>
> If you only need to modify the oEmbed data once, `oembed_result` is probably your best candidate.

To answer your question, here's an example that modifies the Vimeo and YouTube embed parameters returned from the WordPress `wp_oembed_get()` function.

The <iframe> HTML markup is first parsed by PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class, then the embed URL is modified using WordPress' [add_query_arg()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) function:

```php
/**
 *
 */
add_filter( 'oembed_result', function ( $html, $url, $args ) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML( $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' );

    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $iframe_src = $tag->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->value;

        if ( false !== strpos( $iframe_src, 'youtube.com' ) ) {
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
            $url = add_query_arg( array(
                'autohide' => 1,
                'autoplay' => 1,
                'controls' => 2,
                'feature' => null,
                'modestbranding' => 1,
                'playsinline' => 1,
                'rel' => 0,
                'showinfo' => 0,
            ), $iframe_src );
        }

        if ( false !== strpos( $iframe_src, 'vimeo.com' ) ) {
            // https://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding
            $url = add_query_arg( array(
                'autoplay' => 1,
                'badge' => 0,
                'byline' => 0,
                'portrait' => 0,
                'title' => 0,
            ), $iframe_src );
        }

        $tag->setAttribute( 'src', $url );

        $html = $doc->saveHTML();
    }

    return $html;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: pretty solid, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add query args to the end of the URL like so:

```
$videourl = add_query_arg( array('key1' => 'value1' ), $videourl ); // you can add as many as you want in key/value pairs...

$htmlcode = wp_oembed_get( $videourl );
// rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it doesn't seems to be working for me I added `$videourl = add_query_arg( array('title' => '0'), $videourl );`

Comment: What is not working?  You have to be more specific.  What do you get when you var dump $videourl?

Comment: exactly the same thing as before, the output is still `<iframe ... src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/72104173"></iframe>` without the premeters

Comment: Well, I can't really help you further then because what I suggested works 100%.  You should do var dump before the oembed function.  It CANNOT be the same as before unless you didn't do it correctly.

Comment: this is the exact code I have in my theme : `http://pastebin.com/UsED7zGn` can you please implement those parameters ? I tried it like few times and the result is still the same as before for me, so it is probably something I am doing wrong, thanks

Comment: Right, what I am asking for you to try is var_dump( $videourl ); after the "add_query_arg" I told you to add and before wp_oembed_get to see if the parameters are added.

Comment: This is to know if add_query_arg is working or not which I am certain it will work.  So if the end result doesn't work, it would mean wp_oembed_get is stripping the parameters out.

Answer (score 0):

What I guess (didn't try) doesn't work with the other solution might be that appending to the url before asking Vimeo for the embed code might just be ignored by Vimeo.

So what I do is simply parse the response with a RegEx:

```
$htmlcode = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/player.vimeo.com\/video\/[0-9]*)/i", '$1?title=0&portrait=0&byline=0&color=ffffff', $htmlcode);
```